# How to iterate for loop and add to the list in java 8?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8

I am started working with java8 currently.I would like to know how to Iterate for loop n times and add to the list:

```
List orderDayList = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 28).forEach(value -> {
            orderDayList.add(value);
        });
```

The above code is working.Is that correct approach or Is there any other way to achieve ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verbatim it's like this, with a `Collector`:

```
List<Integer> orderDayList =
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 28)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

A bit shorter if we don't care about the type of the `List`:

```
List<Integer> orderDayList =
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 28)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

See [`Collectors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)+[tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#collect).

> Is that correct approach [...]?

Well, modifying the outside world from inside a lambda is considered sloppy form but it doesn't really make a difference for such a simple thing here.

Also, just to get you thinking, your lambda can be written as a method reference:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 28)
         .forEach(orderDayList::add);
```

Comment: Thank you  very much for the answer and spend your time. it is working with method reference .

Comment: Ironically, the most efficient solution is `List<Integer> orderDayList = Arrays.asList(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 28).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new));` because that’s the only solution that comes without any internal data (array) copying.